Blazor server DelegatingHandler cannot access services in DI
I have a project in BlazorServer and I'm creating document metadata (via a REST API) and uploading them (through another REST API).
My action after button click is very simple:
DocumentDto toCreate = new() { ... };
byte[]? fileData = GetFileData();
await _documentService.Create(toCreate, fileData);

My _documentService.Create looks like this:
public async Task Create(DocumentDto input, byte[]? fileData)
{
    try
    {
        var document = await _client.Create(input);
        if (document is not null && fileData is not null)
            await _attachmentClient.Create(document.Id, fileData);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Error during creating document. {serialized}", JsonSerializer.Serialize(input));
    }
}

And finally, here is my _client.Create method:
public async Task<DocumentDto?> Create(DocumentDto input)
{
    var result = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(Endpoint, input);

    return await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<DocumentDto>();
}

And my _attachmentClient.Create method:
public Task Create(Guid documentId, byte[] fileData)
{
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileData);
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
    {
        Name = "file",
        FileName = "Document.pdf"
    };
    content.Add(fileContent, "file", "Document.pdf");
    return _httpClient.PostAsync($"{Endpoint}/{documentId}/pdf", content);
}

Both my clients are registered the same way:
services.AddHttpClient<DocumentClient>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthenticationStateHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient<DocumentAttachmentClient>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthenticationStateHandler>();

My AuthenticationStateHandler looks simple and works just fine for almost all situations:
public class AuthenticationStateHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public AuthenticationStateHandler(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var service = _accessor.HttpContext?.RequestServices.GetService<TokenProvider>();

        // service exists (is not null) for _client but not exists (is null) for _attachmentClient
        if (service is not null)
        {
            var token = await service.GetAccessTokenAsync();
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}

I have made a comment at line in AuthenticationStateHandler what is causing an error for me.
Does anyone have an idea why DelegatingHandler sometimes has access to the correct scope and sometimes not?

You should not use IHttpContextAccessor in blazor server-side. Maybe this is the issue.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0#ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components-blazor
I'm not 100% sure that it would work but you can you try injecting IServiceProviderinto AuthenticationStateHandler and get your services from that. Or even injecting TokenProvider into it, but that might not work for your login because of the lifetime mismatch.

Thank you for your answear but I would prefer to keep my current solution because it works. Just in this situation when I make 2 REST API calls I have problem with appending Token to second call. Right now I changed the REST that it makes just one call and everything works just fine again. That's really weird behavior for me :-(
